# existence of the directional derivative of a function

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Let
$$f:\mathbb R^2\rightarrow\mathbb R,(x,y)↦\begin{cases}1&(\exists z\in\mathbb R\setminus\{0\}:(x,y)=(z,z ^2)\\0 &(\textrm{else})\end{cases}$$

$f$ is obviously not differentiable in $(0,0)$.

But what about any directional derivative $v$ in $(0,0)$? So I have to consider $\lim_{h\rightarrow0}\frac{f(hv)}h$. But why does this limit always exists?

If $f(hv)=0$ for all $h$ the limit is obviously 0 and also for a finite number of $f(hv)=1$.

In the other case $f(hv)=f(h(v_1,v_2))=1$ for $hv_2=h^2v_1^2\Leftrightarrow v_2=hv_1^2$ and now I am stuck. Does this case exists? And what about the limit of $\frac{f(hv)}h$ ? Wouldn't I get "$\frac10$" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0} \frac{f(hv_1,hv_2)}{h}=0$,to prove it we show that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists $\delta>0$ such that for all $h$ : $0<|0-h|<\delta$ implies $|\frac{f(hv_1,hv_2)}{h}-0|<\epsilon$. Setting $\delta=|\frac{v_2}{2v_1^2}|$ should make it work.

(Thanks for Sheldoor for pointing out a mistake in my previous solution)

Comment: two questions: 1) why do you have a $h'$? 2) how do you get $\delta$? I've tried to estimate the absolute value but didn't get along. And won't we get the problem of $f(-,-)=1$ for the limit?

Comment: @jul8 I was applying the defintion of a limit. As for h' I will write h instead. I did not mean to write it

Comment: okay, I see what you mean. but how did you get $\delta$ ?

Comment: @jul8 Is your question why does this delta work ? or you understand that it works and you want to ask how I got it ?

Comment: both ;) I still have problems with the points $(x,y)=(z,z^2)$ for the limit.

Comment: OK to see that it works verify that for all $\epsilon>0$ for all $h$ : $|0-h|<|\frac{v_2^2}{2v_1}|$ implies $|\frac{f(hv_1,hv_2)}{h}-0|<\epsilon$

Comment: okay, I think I got it that it works for $(x,y)=(z,z^2)$. All other points are obvious since $f=0$ there, e.g. $v=(0,1)$. But how did you find this $\delta$ ? Is there any special trick about it?

Comment: @jul8 OK the only worry is he case when $hv_1=h^2v_2^2$. To make sure this we choose $\delta$ such that $h$ is never equal to $v_2^2/v_1$ (hence $hv_1=h^2v_2^2$ cant be satisfied)

Comment: okay, since $v$ is fixed we "cut the case $f(-,-)=1$ off".

Comment: @Amr doesn't it have t be $|\frac{v_1}{v_2^2}|$ ?

Comment: @Sheldoor Yes you are right. I will edit it

Comment: @Amr I've just thought about it one more time and could it be that the first $\delta$ was correct? I've read all the comments and I think in one of you last comments it has to be $hv_2=h^2v^2_1$, doesn't it? And then the old $\delta$ would fit. Am I wrong?

Comment: @sheldoor I'll check it later.

Comment: did you check it? :)

Comment: @sheldoor I will check it now

Comment: @sheldoor It is true the way it is now.

Comment: thanks but why not the other way around? I thought it's $(x,y)=(t,t^2)$, and so $f(hv)=1$ iff $hv_2=h^2v_1^2$ and so $\delta=|\frac{v_2}{2v_1^2}|$ ? where's my mistake?

Comment: @sheldoor OK. you want to choose $\delta>0$ such that for all $h$ such that $0<|h|<\delta$ we have $f(hv_1,hv_2)=0$. Hence we want $hv_1\not= h^2v_2^2$ ,which is equivalent to making sure that $h\not= \frac{v_1}{v_2^2}$.

Comment: @sheldoor Choosing $\delta$ the way I chose it would make sure that this happens

Comment: right, but I thought it's $hv_2=h^2v_1^2$ for $f(hv)=1$...?

Comment: @sheldoor yes and we want to make sure that f(hv) is not $1$. we make sure by choosing delta that will not allow h to satisfy $hv_1=(hv_2)^2$

Comment: @sheldoor got it now ?

Comment: yes, I get the consequences that but Sorry, I don't understand at the moment why $hv_1=h^2v_2^2$. I think it has to be $hv_2=h^2v_1^2$. (because then $f(hv)=1$ and so we want $hv_2\neq h^2v_1^2$ and so we choose $\delta=|\frac{v_2}{2v_1^2}|$ That's the way I am thinking.)

Comment: @sheldoor OK. $f(x,y)=1$ iff $\exists z [x=z,y=z^2]$. This is equivalent to saying $y=x^2$. Thus we want to make sure $hv_2\not=h^2v_1^2$. OK you are right !

Comment: yes, that's what I've meant. Sorry for the complications ;)

Comment: @sheldoor I edited it.